# Cannot parse string with null character

Tags: c++, string, c++11, scgi

I'm trying to write a parser for [SCGI](http://python.ca/scgi/protocol.txt) requests. I'm trying to parse the string described in the example but for some reason I cannot find the position of the second null character, the one that separates the content length value and the next property name.

This is my test string:

```
string scgi_request(
    "70:CONTENT_LENGTH\027\0SCGI\01\0REQUEST_METHOD\0POST\0REQUEST_URI\0" \
    "/deepthought\0,What is the answer to life?"
   , 91);
```

I can find the position of the first null character, position 18. But once I try to find the one after that, the position returned is invalid, off by a few characters, all the way up to position 24.

This is my algorithm:

```
size_t contentLengthEnd = scgi_request.find('\0');
size_t contentLengthValueEnd = scgi_request.find('\0', ++contentLengthEnd);
std::cerr << contentLengthEnd << std::endl; // 19, because I shifted this one forward 
                                            // otherwise I'd always get the same 
                                            // character
std::cerr << contentLengthValueEnd << std::endl; // 24, no clu why.
```

Comment: What's `request`? How, if at all, is it related to `scgi_request`?

Comment: @user657267 It shouldn't be, as in the ctor he specifies the length of the string, and `\0` is not treated as a special character on construction

Comment: I thought creating the string by passing the length would avoid that?

Comment: Sorry I only noticed now that the linebreaks were added.

Comment: The first `\0` is at 18th as you already stated. The next characters `SCGI\01` occupy positions 19-23. The second `\0` is on position 24. Isn't that correct?

Comment: To avoid having the magic number `91` in your code, I'd suggest writing `char const c_request[] = "70:CONTENT etc....";  std::string request( c_request, c_request + sizeof c_request - 1 );`

Comment: @alvits I don't think its ever at position 24. How are you counting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your string starts:

```
"70:CONTENT_LENGTH\027\0SCGI\01\0REQUEST_METHOD\0POST\0REQUEST_URI\0"
```

These outputs are actually correct for the string you gave. I'm guessing you may be overlooking that `\027` is an octal character constant, and so on. The characters and their indices are:

```
16: 'H'
17: '\027'
18: '\0'
19: 'S'
20: 'C'
21: 'G'
22: 'I'
23: '\01'
24: '\0'
25: 'R'
```

Your program finds the first two `'\0'` which are `18` and `24`, but you do `++` on the first one before outputting it, hence the output of `19` and `24`.

If you meant `'\0'` then `'2'` then `'7'` then you'll need to not juxtapose those things, e.g. taking advantage of string literal concatenation:

```
"70:CONTENT_LENGTH\0"
"27\0" 
"SCGI\0"
"1\0"
```

Comment: How can I find the number 27?

Comment: @lapinrigolo as written your string doesn't contain the number 27. `'\027'` is a non-printable character (in ASCII anyway). I've updated my answer to suggest a fix

Comment: @lapinrigolo You're looking for ESC characters in particular? That need's additional logic besides going for `'\0'`!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ the link to spec in the OP suggests that `"\0" "27"` was intended